# union typedef in java

Tags: java, groovy, union

I am trying to read a block in a text plain data and separate this in respective attributes in a structure.

Like as a C/C++ code for clasic example:

```
typedef struct {
        char yyyy[4],
        char mm[2],
        char dd[2]
} ISO;

typedef struct {
        char dd[2],
        char mm[2],
        char yyyy[4]
} JAPAN;

typedef struct {
        char mm[2],
        char dd[2],
        char yyyy[4]
} USA;

typedef union  {
        char  date[8],
        ISO   iso_date,
        JAPAN japan_date,
        USA   usa_date
} date_format;

/////
char date[8] = "20150304";
date_format format = (date_format)date;
printf("%s\n", format->iso_date->yyyy);
```

How to represent this in Java or groovy?

Comment: The date format is only an example, the real problem is to parse a large string to multiple defined fields

Answer (score 1):

1) Java has no structs.

But you can use a class like

```
class ISO {
    public char yyyy = new char[4];
    public char mm = new char[2];
    //etc..
}
```

2) Replace unions with class hierarchies

```
abstract class DateFormat {
    abstract Object getObj();
}

class uISO extends DateFormat {
    ISO iso = new ISO();
    public Object getObj() { return obj; }
}
```

and so on for your other structs.

Answer (score 1):

In groovy (as in Java) is no such construct, as one of the design goals is to prevent the dev from fiddling with memory chunks.  So you would have to come up with some way to to wrap this in classes/interfaces.  Here is an example using groovy `trait`s:

```
// just to have the base for the functions
interface ConcreteDate {
    String getDateChunk()
    String getDay()
    String getMonth()
    String getYear()
}

// actual implementation for ISO
trait ISODate implements ConcreteDate {
    String getYear() { dateChunk[0..3] }
    String getMonth() { dateChunk[4..5] }
    String getDay() { dateChunk[6..7] }
}

// the container, that holds the information
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class DateFormat {
    String dateChunk
}

def df = new DateFormat('20150303')
def isoDate = df as ISODate // cast the object to the trait
assert isoDate.year == '2015'
assert isoDate.month == '03'
assert isoDate.day == '03'
```

Comment: You can also use `def isoDate = df.withTraits ISODate`

Comment: @tim_yates right, but in this case i think it's more readable with the "just one trait"-as, as it's basically a conversion

Comment: I agree, but thought I'd add it for completeness ;-)